# Reduce vertical spacing between two heading tags

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I reduce the spacing between two heading tags? I wish to have the `h2` tag closer to the `h1` tag.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-framework-tsk5b

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Set `margin:0` on the `h1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line-height for headings should generally be 120% so I see where the overlapping issue comes in. I would probably use one of the following methods:

```
h2 {
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

or

```
h2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -2px;
}
```

Although you should add an id to the specific heading you'd like to modify.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `line-height: 0px;` to `.heading h1` and `.heading h2` in css

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It works to a certain degree. The problem I have found with this solution is that when the screen size is minimised and the heading doesn't fit on one line, the heading text overlaps.